# A helpfunction as parameter?

Tags: function, lambda, racket

I dont know how to fix one of my problems.
I have programmed two helpfunction for my main function but it wont work.

```
;;Main function
    (define (FunctionA a b c)
          (/(-(* -1 b) VariableD)aNotNull))

        (check-expect (FunctionA 1 1 1)-1)

;;Helpfunction1:
        (define (VariableD a b c)
            (if (> 0(-(* b b)(* 4 (* a c)))) (error "No negative numbers allowed") 
                (sqrt(-(* b b)(* 4 (* a c)))))) 

        (check-expect (VariableD 0 0 0) 0)
        (check-error (VariableD 1 2 3) "No negative numbers allowed")

;helpfunction2:
        (define (aNotNull a)
          (if (= 0 (* 2 a)) (error "Zerodivisor not allowed")
                 (* 2 a)))

        (check-error (aNotNull 0 ) "Zerodivisor not allowed")
        (check-expect(aNotNull 2) 4)
```

I get the error: expects a number as 2nd argument, given (lambda (a1 a2 a3) ...)
But I dont know how to fix it.

Hope you can help me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(define (FunctionA a b c)
  (/ (- (* -1 b) VariableD) aNotNull))
```

`VariableD` here refers to the function you defined. You probably want to instead call the function with the `a`, `b` and `c` inputs from `FunctionA`, and use the result in `FunctionA`.

The same goes for your usage of `aNotNull`. I'm just inferring that these are the variables you'll want to pass to these functions in this revised `FunctionA`:

```
(define (FunctionA a b c)
  (/ (- (* -1 b) 
        (VariableD a b c))
     (aNotNull a)))
```

Comment: @TobiasHeitkamp In future, instead of using `(* -1 b)`, just use `(- b)`.